# Ambiguous Define Directive in C

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I was looking through some code (PCL) and found this define directive:

```
#define PCL_FEATURE_POINT_TYPES \
  (pcl::PFHSignature125)        \
  (pcl::PFHRGBSignature250)     \
  (pcl::PPFSignature)           \
  (pcl::PPFRGBSignature)        \
  (pcl::NormalBasedSignature12) \
  (pcl::FPFHSignature33)        \
  (pcl::VFHSignature308)        \
  (pcl::Narf36)
```

Can someone explain to me what this is doing (and possibly provide a reference to this feature?). When would something like this be useful?

Comment: There is most likely additional code to further define each of these.  [Look here](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.0.0/classpcl_1_1_default_point_representation_3_01_p_f_h_signature125_01_4.html) for possible clues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh boy, this is messed up.

### Short version

It's a list-like structure (a ["sequence"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/data/sequences.html) in Boost PP parlance) for the preprocessor, used by the [Boost Preprocessor Macros](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) (=black magic); all the `PCL_*_POINT_TYPES` macros are to be used with the `PCL_INSTANTIATE` macro to provide (via convoluted means) explicit instantiations of some templates for the types given in the sequence.

### Long version

***Disclaimer**: I don't have any specific expertise about PCL, I just grepped around a lot; all references to the code are relative to PCL SVN r8781.*

It seems to work like this:

- all the `PCL_*_POINT_TYPES` are macros intended to be used with the [PCL_INSTANTIATE](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/instantiate_8hpp.html#add48b5f4734e652f2b0ea2ff46e55b5a) macro;

  ```
  #define PCL_INSTANTIATE (TEMPLATE, POINT_TYPES) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(PCL_INSTANTIATE_IMPL, TEMPLATE, POINT_TYPES)
  ```
- this macro uses the Boost macro [`BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/seq_for_each.html) to extract each element from that ["sequence"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/data/sequences.html), and feed it to `PCL_INSTANTIATE_IMPL`:

  ```
  #define PCL_INSTANTIATE_IMPL (r, TEMPLATE, POINT_TYPE) BOOST_PP_CAT(PCL_INSTANTIATE_, TEMPLATE)(POINT_TYPE)
  ```
- `PCL_INSTANTIATE_IMPL`, in turn, uses [`BOOST_PP_CAT`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/cat.html) to concatenate `PCL_INSTANTIATE_` with the `TEMPLATE` parameter of `PCL_INSTANTIATE`. and sticks the point type (i.e. the one extracted from the list of the `PCL_*_POINT_TYPES` macro) after it, in parentheses.

So, when writing

```
PCL_INSTANTIATE(Search, PCL_POINT_TYPES)
```

(taken from [here](http://svn.pointclouds.org/pcl/trunk/search/src/search.cpp), line 43)

what actually happens is

```
PCL_INSTANTIATE_Search(pcl::PointXYZRGBA) PCL_INSTANTIATE_Search(pcl::PointXYZRGB) PCL_INSTANTIATE_Search(pcl::PointXYZRGBL) PCL_INSTANTIATE_Search(pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal) PCL_INSTANTIATE_Search(pcl::PointSurfel)
```

Now, `PCL_INSTANTIATE_Search` (and all its siblings `PCL_INSTANTIATE_T` where T is the argument to `PCL_INSTANTIATE`) are in turn *other* macros, defined elsewhere. Such macros typically expand to explicit template instantiations:

```
#define PCL_INSTANTIATE_Search(T) template class PCL_EXPORTS pcl::search::Search<T>;
```

(from [here](http://svn.pointclouds.org/pcl/trunk/search/include/pcl/search/impl/search.hpp), line 208; notice the semicolon at the end of the macro)

In the end, it becomes:

```
template class PCL_EXPORTS pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>;
template class PCL_EXPORTS pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZRGB>;
template class PCL_EXPORTS pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZRGBL>;
template class PCL_EXPORTS pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal>;
template class PCL_EXPORTS pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointSurfel>;
```

(newlines added)

Thus, the whole thing boils down to a series of explicit template instantiations.

---

To sum up again: `PCL_*_POINT_TYPES` is a "preprocessor list" of types to be used with `PCL_INSTANTIATE`; `PCL_INSTANTIATE` takes the list, and, with strange sorceries, instantiates the template relative to the specified suffix (e.g. `Search` in this case) for all the types in the list.

So, AFAICT, the whole point of this thing is to provide a concise mean to explicitly instantiate a template class over all the specified types. I didn't look further, but I suppose that this is done to avoid the need of "normal" ("on the spot") templates expansions in the code that uses the library, maybe to speed up compilation times, to limit the possible templates expansions only to those definite types, to keep them in a shared library (to keep down the client executable size), or for something even different.