# Can you do file IO in c++ metaprogramming?

Tags: c++, templates, io, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

Realistically  I don't think this is good practice. But because c++ metaprogramming is Turing complete, I've been looking into this for completeness sake. In production I won't use it, but for fun I want to do some File IO at compile time. Anyone know how to do File IO using metaprogramming at compile time? Also equivalently as cool run scripts during compile time using C++ using metaprogramming?

Comment: If it helps, instantiating templates is sort of like outputting definitions to your source file. Does that count?

Comment: Does `#include`ing a file count as I/O?

Comment: BTW, being Turing complete does not mean you can do IO.

Comment: Maybe #include is in the write direction. It's simple reading, maybe using that it would be possible to say parse json. But the include directive can't be an input to the template.

Comment: Fortunately it's not possible, C++ TMP is abused enough like that, if it was possible to do file IO this whole kludge would be used for even more inappropriate stuff.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, But compile time regex!

Comment: @chris: it's immoral to even *think* about that. >:(

Comment: @MatteoItalia, Fine, I'll think about triply nested preprocessor loops instead.

Comment: @MatteoItalia we already have tools to compile then run to pregenerate source code, then the actual source code gets compiled. Example MPFR has a prestep to compile a tool which generates a a table (of source code) for optimizing floating point math. Then the multiprecion library gets compiled. Many large projects are like this.

Comment: @chris: actually, when I saw what they do with [boost.preprocessor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19106620/214671) I seriously asked myself what they were trying to prove. Seriously guys, that mess is a non-problem, just use a script to generate that stuff and move on. The same holds for boost.spirit.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, If nothing else, I really enjoy it as a thought exercise. Learning how they automatically detected the level of nesting for `BOOST_PP_REPEAT` and how it all fit together was a great moment.

Comment: Yes @MatteoItalia I agree :). In my original question I already mentioned I don't think File IO in metaprogramming will be good practice for any production environment. But it would be fun to know it would be possible, and how to do it.

Comment: @over_optimistic: of course, I was going off on a tangent :) seriously speaking, I really doubt there's a way to do file IO, since the compilation of a file normally shouldn't generate anything besides the object module - in facts, if in a TMP "program" you want to show a message more-or-less-portably you have to resort to fictitious errors or warnings.

Comment: Just what we need, C++ source code that deletes all your files just from compiling it (never mind actually running it)  :)

Comment: The very first template metaprogramming program produced as output at compile time, a list of prime numbers. The format was a bit constrained by the format of that particular compiler warnings, but other than that, it did produce output...

Comment: Others have pointed out that *C++* metaprogramming cannot do I/O.  If you consider metaprogramming as "programs that write/modify programs", then non-C++ metaprogramming tools can be found that *can* do arbitrary I/O.  See Program Transformation Systems (PTS): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation  Such tools can be used to read a source code, and extract data from it; or, read some file, generate some code/data and insert into a program at an appropriate spot.  Some of these PTS tools are strong enough to do such actions *on* C++ source code.  That seems to match your scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, you cannot. Not in any ordinary sense of the word.

However, on the bright side file I/O is not a requirement of Turing completeness and indeed is not a requirement of any programming language definition. From the viewpoint of a programming language file I/O is merely a source of unexpected data, or a place to send bits that are no longer wanted, or an interesting connection between certain parts of the language whereby bits deposited on one occasion are available on another.

So at some level of abstraction the compiler's internal storage can be regarded as a repository (or file system) which comes pre-loaded with the source code of the program and a number of symbols. The metaprogramming script can interact (perform I/O) on this repository, accepting input code and symbols and emitting generated code and symbols, some of which it previously generated.

But the answer is still no. There is no file I/O.